# SQL complex query for three fields

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with this structure:

```
Field A  Field B  Field C
a1       b1       t1
a1       b1       t2
a2       b1       t1
a2       b1       t2
```

Field A and Field B are related, in a way that there are several a* for a given b*.

I need to list either Field A or Field B that meet the following criteria:

- b* has several a*
- a* has 1 to N t*
- if two a* belonging to the same b* have different t*, then I need to list that a* or its parent b*

In the previous example, nothing whould be listed because b1 has a1 and a2, and both a1 and a2 have the same information: they both have t1 and t2.

In the next example, I need to detect that a1 and a2, belonging to b1, have different information (a1: t1 and t2; b1: only t1, it doesn't have t2).

```
Field A  Field B  Field C
a1       b1       t1
a1       b1       t2
a2       b1       t1
a3       b2       t3
```

The query would show either a1, a2 or b1.

I know this is complicated but I need to get that information.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, I'm a bit confused about your use of 'either' and 'or'; I don't think databases can handle options like that.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that it doesn't matter to me if the query returns a1, a2 or b1, I want to get any of those values, because from a1 and a2 I can get the b1 value, so the query can try to get either Field A or Field B.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to add the explanation to why there's nothing returned in the first example to the requirements.

Solution to example 1:

```
SELECT
t.B,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.A)
FROM
t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
  B,
  A
  FROM
  t
  GROUP BY B, A
  HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT C) > 1
) q ON t.A = q.A AND t.B = q.B /* a* has 1 to N t* */

WHERE t.B IN (
  SELECT sq.B FROM (
    SELECT st.B, GROUP_CONCAT(st.C ORDER BY st.C) AS gcc FROM t AS st GROUP BY st.B, st.A
  ) sq GROUP BY sq.B HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gcc) > 1
) /* if two a* belonging to the same b* have different t*, then I need to list that a* or its parent b* */

GROUP BY t.B
HAVING
COUNT(DISTINCT t.A) > 1 /* b* has several a* */
;
```

- play around with it if you want in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5b2d0/11/0)

Your second example is not clear to me. But I guess you mean this:

```
SELECT
B, A
FROM
t
WHERE A IN ('a1', 'a2')
GROUP BY B, A
HAVING 
COUNT(DISTINCT C) > 1
OR 
COUNT(*) = 1;
```

- [sqlfiddle for Example 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/731bb/2/0)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, both examples 1 and 2 are examples of the same query... so the SQL query must be the same. The difference is that in the first example the query returns nothing, while in the second example the query returns b1 (or, alternatively, a1/a2, because I can get the b1 value from a1/a2).

Comment: Then your question is totaly unclear. You better rephrase your entire question with exact requirements and even better, you provide a desired result based on maybe more sample data.